# How to use the Axiom of Extension to prove the equality of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I have a problem understanding the *Axiom of Extension*.

The axiom states that $A = B \iff \forall x \  (x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B)$. In my understanding, this is a bi-conditional statement that means two things:

1. if two sets are the same, then they have the same elements, *i.e.*, $(A = B) \Rightarrow \forall x \  (x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B)$; and
2. it two sets have the same elements, then they are the same, *i.e.*, $\forall x \  (x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B) \Rightarrow (A=B)$

Now I want to use the axiom of extension to prove that $A = A$.

**Proof:** The statement $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in A$ is obviously true. Therefore, the statement $x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in A$ is also true. By the *Axiom of Extension*, since we have $\forall x \ (x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in A)$, we get $A = A$, *i.e.*, $(x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in A) \Rightarrow A=A$.

The problem is that I do not understand how to prove the other side of the implication, *i.e.*, that $A = A \Rightarrow (x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in A)$, because I am not sure what $A=A$ means, other than that both sets have the same elements.

So my question in essence is the following: Is it necessary to prove the other side of the implication? and is my understanding of the axiom correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Personally I always see $A=B$ as the statement that $A$ and $B$ are both notations for *the same set*, so that 1) is direct and is not a part of the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality).

Comment: "Is it necessary to prove the other side of the implication?" NO; if you have proved that $x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in A$, you can use the axiom to conclude that $A=A$. From the Axiom in form $A = B \leftrightarrow \varphi$, you derive by logic ([Biconditional Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_elimination)) both: $A=B \to \varphi$ and $\varphi \to A=B$.

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA, that cleared it up a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think there is a confusion in your mind between proving a
> bi-conditional statement and ***using*** this statement. .

Suppose you want to prove a bi-conditional statement, in that case, you actually have to show that the implication " works" in both directions.

But here you only want to use this biconditional, *as a premise in your reasoning.*

The structure of the proof you want to achieve is as follows :

(1) $LHS \iff RHS$

(2) $RHS$ is true, because...

(3) Therefore $LHS$ is true

with $LHS : A=A$

and $RHS : \forall (x) [ x\in A \iff x\in A]$

- Example. Suppose I want to prove that figure $F$ is a square.

I know that :  F is a square iff F is a parallelogram with 1 right angle and 4 equal sides. ( Note that I do not prove this statement, I use it as a given and as a premise in my reasoning).

I prove the $RHS$ , namely that $F$ is a parallelogram with 1 right angle and 4 equal sides.

I conclude that the $LHS$ is true, namely that $F$ is a square.

Answer (score 0):

**View Point 1 :**

You have Proved 1-Direction.
The other Direction is almost same:
Let $A=A$.
Then $\forall x : x \in A \implies x \in A$
& $\forall x : x \in A \impliedby x \in A$
Hence $\forall x : x \in A \iff x \in A$
Hence, $(A=A) \implies (\forall x : x \in A \iff x \in A)$

Overall, we have, $(A=A) \iff (\forall x : x \in A \iff x \in A)$

**View Point 2 :**

In certain treatments, The Axiom of Extension is not BiDirectional.
In wiki ([Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality#Formal_statement)) , it says:

> In Zermelo–Fraenkel Axioms, the Implication is 1-Way.
> $\forall A \forall B (\forall X (X \in A \iff X \in B) \implies A = B)$
> The converse of this axiom follows from the Substitution Property of Equality.
> $\forall A \forall B ( A = B \implies \forall X ( X \in A \iff X \in B ) )$
> In this case, the Proof of $A=A$ will use the Substitution Property of Equality.

**View Point 3 :**

In certain treatments, there is no Primitive Equality.
Then that becomes the "Definition" of Equality, using new Axiom with Substitution Property.
In high level, $\forall X : P(X) \implies \forall Y : P(Y)$ is the Substitution Property.
In this case too, the Proof of $A=A$ will use the Substitution Property & the "Definition" of Equality.

**View Point 4 :**

In certain treatments, [ Eg : [Logic & Structure by Dirk van Dalen](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/573469.Logic_and_Structure) ] , Identity (Equality) itself has multiple Axioms, which interact with the Axiom of Extension, giving rise to new ways to look at $A=A$.